# Condición si un valor pertenece a una tabla, Macros Excel

Tags: excel, vba, macros

Estoy realizando una extensa macro en excel, sin embargo he llegado a un punto donde no puedo continuar y es el siguiente

Tengo una tabla: "TablaPrueba[Prueba]"

En un formulario quiero validar si un valor ingresado en un textbox se encuentra en dicha tabla, el ejemplo que tengo es:

```
If valor <> "TablaPrueba[Prueba]" Then
MsgBox "El Valor no se encuentra en la tabla"

Else
MsgBox "El Valor si se ha encontrado en la tabla"

End If
```

Lo que deseo saber es si: `If valor <> "TablaPrueba[Prueba]" Then` es la forma correcta de escribirlo, o no es valido escribirlo así o hay que hacer la validación de otra forma?

Answer (score 1):

El concepto `TablaPrueba[Prueba]` en realidad hace mención al campo `Prueba` entero de tu tabla `TablaPrueba`, es decir, es un rango.

Tu código lo que hace es comparar un valor con un rango entero, y eso es incorrecto. Cuando usas un if, puedes poner varias condiciones, pero solamente puedes comparar 1 valor con otro valor.

En tu caso, creo que la mejor opción es usar la función COUNTIF en VBA, que equivale al CONTAR.SI. Esta función te permite especificar un rango, y contará cuantas veces aparece un valor. Si la cuenta es 0, es que no existe.

> [Función CONTAR.SI (en
> Excel)](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/contar-si-funci%C3%B3n-contar-si-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34)
>
> [Función COUNTIF (lo mismo pero en
> VBA)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.countif)

Así que lo mejor es que tu código sea así:

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("TablaPrueba[Prueba]"), valor) = 0 Then
    MsgBox "El Valor no se encuentra en la tabla"
Else
    MsgBox "El Valor si se ha encontrado en la tabla"
End If
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias!